# 404 Error The requested URL was not found on the server

Tags: python, flask, migration, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I have a app base on miguelgrinberg tutorial, it's contains of:

```
flask
 run.py
 config.py
 db_migrate.py
 db_craete.py
 db_repository
 app
     __init__.py
     viw.py
     model.py
     form.py
     tmp
     static
```

I put some changes for model and then use ./db_migrate.py to update data base But I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/home/peg/flask/app/ __ init __.py", line 13, in <module>
    from app import view, model
```

so I delete from app import view, model line in  (__ init __.py ) and run db_migrate.py But when I run the app got 404 error so where is the problem and how can I solve it?

> __ init __.py

```
#!flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
lm = LoginManager()
lm.init_app(app)
lm.login_view = 'login'

from app import view, model # should delete this line to solve error Traceback
```

> db_migrate.py

```
  #!flask/bin/python
    import imp
    from migrate.versioning import api
    from app import db # Error here for traceback
    from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
   .... other stuff....
```

..

> view.py

```
@lm.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))


@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = current_user


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
@login_required
def index():
    user = g.user
    return render_template('index.html',
            user = user,
            title ='Home')
```

Comment: Please include the whole traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the directory from "tmp" to the Flask default "templates".

If you must you can override Flask's default templates directory name like this.

**In your __init__.py File**

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='tmp')
```

[source | Flask API .10  - Application Object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#application-object)